# What is this strange symbol in Microsoft Word and how can I use it?

Tags: microsoft-word

What is this symbol in Microsoft Word?

[image]

What is it for?

How can I use and delete it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

It marks the end of the text in a table cell (all characters in above picture are the same).

Positioning your cursor to the left of them after the table enables you to insert new row / column in the table (right-click - insert; or simply press <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

You can't delete / insert them, but you can hide by pressing "show/hide" in home tab - paragraph group; or with the keyboard shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>(</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

i think it part of show/hide invisible characters (space, breaks etc)

find this in the home ribbon and click that

[image: show/hide]