# What does the meaning of the "circle inside cross" symbol in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

What does the meaning of the below symbol and how can I remove this. In a MS-Word document file, I can't formatting a tables text. That's why I'm displaying all hidden text and formatting characters but I can't understand what is the below symbol and what is the purpose of it.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is this strange symbol in Microsoft Word and how can I use it?](https://superuser.com/questions/1157126/what-is-this-strange-symbol-in-microsoft-word-and-how-can-i-use-it)

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Yes, thank you.